# Show button when select option and checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have two form fields, one with select options and one with checkboxes. I want to show the button when both are checked/selected. How do I write the code so that when an option is selected in the first form group and at least one checkbox is selected in the second form group the button shows. Any help would be appreciated...

MY HTML IS:

```
<div class="row fourth-row hide"> <!--HIDE THIS-->

       <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3">
         <form role="form">
           <fieldset class="usergroup-2 usergroup">
             <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option class="activate">Usergroup</option>
                <option class="activate-3" value="usergroup">Moderator</option>
                <option class="activate-3" value="usergroup">Registered user</option>
                <option class="activate-3" value="usergroup">Super user</option>
              </select>
            </div> <!--/.form-group-->
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div> <!--/.col-xs-4--> 

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="btn-group options hide" id="checkboxes-div-2" class="checkbox-div">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle open-second" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ><!--DISABLE THIS-->
           Select one or more options <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu check-second" id="close-out" role="menu" name="form3">
           <li class="option">
             <a class="checkall show-cross-2" href="#">Check all</a>
             <a class="uncheckall">Uncheck all</a>
           </li>
           <li><strong>Group 1</strong></li>
           <li class="option">
             <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
               <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #1 for group 1
             </label>
           </div>
         </li>
         <li class="option">
           <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
             <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #2 for group 1
           </label>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="option">
         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #3 for group 1
         </label>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li><strong>Group 2</strong></li>
     <li class="option">
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
         <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Forum
       </label>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="option">
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Ipsum
     </label>
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="option">
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Dorol
   </label>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div> <!--/.btn-group-->
</div> <!--/.col-xs-6-->

<div class="col-xs-1">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm hidden-cross-2 hide">X</button>
</div>
```

JQUERY I HAVE TRIED:

```
 $(".dropdown-menu .only-this").change(function() {
    if ($('.usergroup option:selected').is(':checked')) && ('.dropdown-menu input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked"))  {
        $(".btn-danger").show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ginalolli/dsfe307m/

Comment: Can't understand. You want when at least one checkbox from two groups is checked and what option in dropdown?

Comment: When at least one option is selected in the first form field and when at least one checkbox is selected in the second form field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your select so that your first option has no value:

```
<option class="activate" value="">Usergroup</option>
```

You can use the following jQuery:

```
var select = $('.form-control'),
    checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

select.add(checkboxes).on('change', function() {
    if (select.val() != '' && checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0) {
        $(".btn-danger").show();
    } else {
        $(".btn-danger").hide();
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dsfe307m/12/)

I wasn't sure what `.dropdown-menu .only-this` was so I bound the events to the change of the select and the checkboxes